# Visual Studio 2010 addin writing articles/tutorials?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, mef, vsx, visual-studio-addins

Does anyone know of some good articles / tutorials on writing addins/plugins for Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- [Getting Started with Extending Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff677564.aspx)
- The [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=2680) for 2010
- The [VS2010 beta forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/vsprerelease,visualstudioprerelease,netdevelopmentprerelease,vstsprerelease)
- [Visual Studio 2010 New Features, Extensibility Points and Partner Opportunities](http://blogs.msdn.com/terryclancy/archive/2009/05/19/visual-studio-2010-new-features-extensibility-points-and-partner-opportunities.aspx)

Most of the information on add-ins is in the SDK.

Comment: This first link no longer exists.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the new [Visual Studio 10 extensibility samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VS10XSamples)

- 6th July 2009 Sample - VSIX MEF
  Component Project Template added
- 7th July 2009 Sample - MEF Container
  added
- 10th July 2009 Sample - VS
  Package MEF Container Project
  Template added
- 15th July 2009 Sample - DSL Store Locking added