# How can I make a Visual Studio addon that posts my code to a website?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, add-on

I'm trying to create an extension for Visual Studio that will post code from a given method and possibly the error message to my blog. I'm building a small wordpress blog for common mistakes I make so I can browser them later on possibly and help people out with the same issues.

Is this possible in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is simply if this is possible, then the answer is that yes, it is.

You can use the wordpress api to post blog entries.

For the visual studio part, you should be able to use WPF or winforms.

Comment: I know I can use the API, I don't know if I can make a Window type prompt inside of Visual Studio to allow me to post it.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia - answer updated. You can use any WPF and winforms in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can make a Visual Studio addon that includes WPF or WinForms UI to do anything you want.

Comment: SLaks can you share a link with some demo code on how to create a simple window within Visual Studio?

Comment: The same way you create a simple window in an ordinary EXE.

Comment: Apparently they are called Add-ins; I'll search for those.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146776/visual-studio-2010-addin-writing-articles-tutorials