# C# tool tip Addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

hi i want to develop an addin to Visual studio in c# to display a tool tip text when the cursor lands on a particular text..

ex- if there is a line called Hello i want it to popup a tool tip "hello world " when i land the mouse cursor on it
please help me out

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio 2010 addin writing articles/tutorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146776/visual-studio-2010-addin-writing-articles-tutorials)

Rather than just ask how to do an entire task, ask a specific question about a problem you're having doing it. There are lots of tutorials around on how to make a VS2010 addin (or any other version). Start coding one and see where the problems end up coming from.

Comment: Thanks paul...but the problem is whether an addin would help me to do that or do i need package or something

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the text cursor, then this is possible with an add-in. In fact, it's quite easy. Just handle [TextDocumentKeyPressEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.textdocumentkeypressevents.aspx). There's also a complete add-in example in that article.

If you mean hovering a text with the mouse pointer, there's no direct support for it in add-in. You would need to use some global mouse events handler and manually retrieve the text under the pointer. Or, I believe, VS packages have better support for such tasks.