# Adding a toolbar button for a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I want to add a toolbar button to the toolbar which takes me to the TFS Builds view.

It is only available as a shortcut, TeamFoundationContextMenus.Commands.GoToBuilds, with the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+0, B so I cannot add it as I normally would.
The other views, such as Pending Changes are available as buttons, but not Builds.

I found this workaround: [Adding a Visual Studio toolbar button for a command that is only available as a keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394784/adding-a-visual-studio-toolbar-button-for-a-command-that-is-only-available-as-a) but it is for VS2010 and uses macros which were taken out of VS2012.

Does anyone know if it is possible to add a keyboard shortcut as a toolbar button?