# Add ReSharper_ToggleSuspended as toolbar button

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

I'd like to map the `ReSharper_ToggleSuspended` command to a button on a toolbar in VS 2012, but the command is not listed in the ReSharper category of Commands availabe in  Customize > Commands dialog.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394784/adding-a-visual-studio-toolbar-button-for-a-command-that-is-only-available-as-a and the comment about Visual Commander for VS 2012

Answer (score 29):

Borrowed from the suggestion on the R# issue tracker for this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-303216).

In the VS Package Manager Console, you can run these commands to add the `ReSharper_ToggleSuspended` command to an existing toolbar named "R#".

```
$cmdBarName = "R#"
$cmdName = "ReSharper_ToggleSuspended"
$cmdText = "R# Active"
$toolbarType = [EnvDTE.vsCommandBarType]::vsCommandBarTypeToolbar

#----If you have a command bar you want to use---
#$cmdBar =  $dte.CommandBars.Item($cmdBarName)
# - or you can create one -
$cmdBar = $dte.Commands.AddCommandBar($cmdBarName, $toolbarType)
#------

$cmdItem = $dte.Commands.Item($cmdName).AddControl($cmdBar, 1)
$cmdItem.Caption = $cmdText
```

[image]

You can use any existing toolbar, or create one from scratch. I had originally added a new toolbar using the UI but updated this to include how to create one, as well as to update the Button text to use $cmdText.

Rick Strahl has a decent [writeup](https://blogs.msmvps.com/carlosq/2009/10/23/vs-2010-and-the-commandbarpopup-interface/) on the command bars, if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the `Resharper_ToggleSuspended` command relates to the 'Suspend' button under `Tools`->`Options...`->`Resharper`->`General`. It seems you can't have items from the Options dialogue as commands. Possibly your only choice is to assign a keyboard shortcut to it.